# Unexpected output - Choosing the lowest number from an array

Tags: arrays, c, output

I want to find the smallest number from the numbers in an array entered by the user.
The output I am getting for the program is a vague number -858993460. This is generally because of a type mismatch but they seem alright here. Not able to think of a solution. Thanks for the help!

````html
    
```

    //
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int a;
        int i;
        int num[25];
        printf("Enter the 25 numbers:");
        for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            a = num[i];
            if (a < num[i+1])
            {
                a = a;
            }
            else
                a = num[i+1];
        }
        printf("Lowest number is %d\n", a);
        return 0;
    
    }
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work for you. Just remove the `else` statement and bring `a=num[i]` inside `if` statement and consider the first element is the minimum element by doing this `a = num[0]`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int i;
    int num[25];

    printf("Enter the 25 numbers:");

    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    a = num[0];
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++)
    {     
        if (num[i] < a)
        {
             a = num[i]; 
        }
    }
    printf("Lowest number is %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `i+1` statement. When on `i = 24`, the next index is out of bounds. Instead of throwing an error, C lets you access that part of memory, giving you whatever garbage data was stored there. That's why you're getting such a random result.